# Javascript DropDownList not changing Input box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using this same javascript for a label so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong with the submit field.

Here is my view:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.OrderGasModel

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>   
    $(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();   }); 
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){   
        $("#AccountId").change(function(){
            var val=$(this).val();
            $("#contactNumber").load("@Url.Action("GetMyValue","GasOrder")", { custid : val });
            document.forms[0].Amount.focus();   }); }); 
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Order Gas"; }

<h2>Order Gas</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("OrderGasSuccess", "GasOrder", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Submit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Information - all fields required</legend>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts)
                    </div>

                  <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TankPercent)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TankPercent, new { @class = "GenericTextBox" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TankPercent)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "GenericTextBox" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                      <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="GenericTextBox"/>
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                    </div>
                  <div class="editor-field">
                    <input type="text" id="contactNumber" class="GenericTextBox"/>

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                  </div>


                  <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Message)            
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>

                </fieldset>

            </div>
        }
```

Any my method being called:

```
public string GetMyValue(string custid)
{
  var cust = _client.GetCustomerByCustomerId(Guid.Parse(custid));
  return String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(cust.TotalBalance));
}
```

The GetMyValue method is being called and returning back a value. The dropdownlist is being populated with values also.

When I change the value in the ddl, the GetMyValue does fire but the input box does not get the value.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**==== UPDATE ====**

I made the changes as suggested below. I'm not sure if I did it right since I am getting this message:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'val' is undefined

This is my view with the changes:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.OrderGasModel

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>

<script>
    $.post("@Url.Action("GetMyValue","GasOrder")",  { custid : val }, function(r){
        $("#contactNumber").val(r.ContactNumber);
    });
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Order Gas";
}

<h2>Order Gas</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("OrderGasSuccess", "GasOrder", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Submit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Information - all fields required</legend>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts)
                    </div>

                  <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TankPercent)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TankPercent, new { @class = "GenericTextBox" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TankPercent)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "GenericTextBox" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                      <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="GenericTextBox"/>
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                    </div>
                  <div class="editor-field">
                    <input type="text" id="contactNumber" class="GenericTextBox"/>

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                  </div>


                  <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Message)            
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>

                </fieldset>

            </div>
        }
```

I'm new to javascript so I apologize if this is a trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

Because .load function " sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data" (http://api.jquery.com/load/). But to change input text you need to change value attribute. 
To fix this issue you can
1)return JSON from GetMyValue action 
2)use .post(you can get problems with caching if use .get)  instead of .load and in success callback set value from response. Something like

```
$.post("@Url.Action("GetMyValue","GasOrder")",  { custid : val }, function(r){
    $("#contactNumber").val(r.ContactNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult GetMyValue(string custid) 
{          
    var cust = _client.GetCustomerByCustomerId(Guid.Parse(custid));  
    return Json(String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(cust.TotalBalance)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#AccountId").change(function(){
            var val=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMyValue","GasOrder")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: val,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#contactNumber").val(result);
                }
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have made these changes but it is giving me Error: Internal Server Error and not reaching my GetMyValue method.

Comment: Can you check your scripts with using browser's script tools. (for firefox firebug, or chrome inspect element) and track your script. Debug your codes. What is the error details.

Comment: This codes it tested and commonly using. You can find a lot of example about this codes.